# nginx ignore missing HTTP headers

Tags: nginx, proxy

Is there any way to tell nginx to ignore missing HTTP headers when proxying requests?

There is an existing proprietary HTTP Server sending requests without any header. The Server can not be configured. I need various endpoints from this server in a web application. Therefore I want to setup my nginx to proxy requests to this server. I have location configuration in my regular server.

```
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:80/;
    }
```

When calling corresponding URIs nginx complains:

`upstream sent no valid HTTP/1.0 header while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: ....`

Is there any way to tell nginx not to expect any headers, and just to forward the received payload?

Thanks for your help!

Kind regards,
Andreas

Edit: Ok, found server is using http 0.9, when calling curl directly to the server threw an error:
`curl: (1) Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed`
Using the option --http0.9 got the desired result. (Which is received in a browser without further ado). Any chance to tell nginx to proxy to an http 0.9 server?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure nginx to ignore missing headers by setting the proxy_ignore_headers directive to "X-Accel-Expires" and "Expires". This will tell nginx to ignore those specific headers and not expect them to be present when proxying requests.

You can add this to the location block in your nginx configuration:

```
proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires;
```

Additionally, proxy_pass_request_headers off; could be used, this tells nginx to ignore all headers passed to the proxied server.

As for the payload, as long as the underlying protocol is HTTP, it should be fine, as the payload will be sent in the body of the HTTP request.

So your location block could look like this

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:80/;
    proxy_pass_request_headers off;
}
```

Please note that this is may not be recommended, as the missing headers may contain important information like authentication and should be handled correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. proxy_pass_request_headers just eliminates sending headers to the proxied server. It does not affect the response. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass_request_headers